# I am trying Websocket.. I don't know javascript to onMessage Method of java.. How can I use javascript function?

Tags: java, websocket

I don't know javascript to `onMessage` method of Java. How can I use javascript function?

I tried to send data using `ajax` and `json`.

I want Console looking `System.out.println(message)` of `onMessage` method

**broadcast.html**

```
    var textarea = document.getElementById("messageWindow");
    var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8888/hanyoung/broadcasting');
    var inputMessage = document.getElementById('inputMessage');
    webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
      onError(event)
    };

    webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
      onOpen(event)
    };

    webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
      onMessage(event)
    };

    function onMessage(event) {
        textarea.value += "상대 : " + event.data + "\n";
    }

    function onOpen(event) {
        textarea.value += "연결 성공\n";
    }

    function onError(event) {
      alert(event.data);
    }

    function send() {
        textarea.value += "나 : " + inputMessage.value + "\n";
        webSocket.send(inputMessage.value);
        inputMessage.value = "";
    }
```

**Broadsocket.java**

```
public class Broadsocket {
    private static Set<Session> clients = Collections
        .synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(message);
        synchronized (clients) {
            // Iterate over the connected sessions
            // and broadcast the received message
            for (Session client : clients) {
                if (!client.equals(session)) {
                    client.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        // Add session to the connected sessions set
        System.out.println(session);
        clients.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        // Remove session from the connected sessions set
        clients.remove(session);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: I want looking sysout of onMessage method. But I can't and I don't know way..

Comment: So, you just want to print the received message, right? or you are saying that your `onMessage` method is never invoked?

Comment: right.. you completely understand..

Comment: Does your javascript `onOpen` returns okey? I mean, do you really open a websocket connection?

Comment: yeah~ I checked a websocket connection. So.. chatting program run.. But I want that.

Comment: That's weird ... If the socket is being opened and the message is being sent... the JAVA method `onMessage` should be invoked and the `System.out.println` should happen .... Question: how do you run the `Broadsocket`? are you running a webserver (Wildfly, for example) ?

Comment: localhost running a apache webserver.. (ex : localhost:8080/packagename/Broadcasting) Websocket is not problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the `System.out.println` is not being recorded in the server logs?

Comment: Recently I got it!! websocket.send(message) in javascript function send onMessage method and I looked console.log Thanks Carlitos Way